# Proxying Multiple API requests with Create React App with React-Scripts version 3.4.1

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, react-scripts

I am currently using the older version of React Script version 1.5.1. I want to upgrade my react app(react-scripts v 3.4.1) but in doing so I break the proxy structure defined in my package.json.

My current JSON has

```
"proxy": {
  "/ossapi": {
    "target": "http://localhost:8002"
  },
  "/pcp": {
    "target": "http://test.corp.test.com:8004"
  },
  "/ossOps": {
    "target": "http://test.corp.test.com:8085"
  },
  "/ems": {
    "target": "http://test.corp.test.com:8001"
  }
}
```

I want a similar setup for my app even after I upgrade to new React-scripts version 3.4.1 as I have done lots of development and don't want to restart from scratch again.
when I change the react-scripts version to the latest stable 3.4.1, it keeps on throwing failed to parse json error.

Please advise.

The following is the error I get:

```
npm ERR! code EJSONPARSE
npm ERR! file /Users/dhrumit.sheth/Documents/Dev/stash/console-app/package.json
npm ERR! JSON.parse Failed to parse json
npm ERR! JSON.parse Unexpected token } in JSON at position 1438 while parsing near '...git push --tags",
npm ERR! JSON.parse   },
npm ERR! JSON.parse "proxy": [
npm ERR! JSON.parse   "/os...'
npm ERR! JSON.parse Failed to parse package.json data.
npm ERR! JSON.parse package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"proxy" in package.json works for single endpoint I believe. For more advanced configuration you need to create `setpProxy.js` file in project root folder, install `http-proxy-middleware` and put your configurations there. Code will look like this.

```
module.exports = function(app) {
  app.use(
    '/ossapi',
    createProxyMiddleware({
      target: 'http://localhost:8002',
      changeOrigin: true,
    })
  );
  app.use(
    '/pcp',
    createProxyMiddleware({
      target: 'http://test.corp.test.com:8004',
      changeOrigin: true,
    })
  );
};
```

And rest same.
[documentation](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/) here.

Comment: Thank you for your response. But in the case of multiple proxy and target, do we pass object or array?

Comment: You dont pass array or object @Mave7. I have modified my answer for your use case. Please see if it works.