# use environment variables in package.json

Tags: reactjs, node.js, package.json, .env

How to use environment variables in .json file.

For example, I have a PROXY variable in .env

```
PROXY=http://localhost:5000
```

So how can I use this PROXY variable in package.json

```
{
  "name": "name",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "proxy": process.env.PROXY,
  "private": true,
  ...
}
```

Comment: I dont recommend, but if you really want to do that, write a script that reads the .env and update the json

Comment: @Feijoes  my purpose in using env variables is to use different proxies in the production environment and the test environment. If you have a better solution I will be grateful.

Comment: Are you using react? Angular? Js vanila?

Comment: I am using React

Comment: maybe this could be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61472399/proxying-multiple-api-requests-with-create-react-app-with-react-scripts-version